# connecting to SSH and sending Multiple commands in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am connecting to the server and then getting the 'myServerLog' and saving to my local 'log2.txt'.
And then , I want to come out of the myServerLog which can be done by Ctrl + C manually.
My script is as follows,

```
ssh -i myServer 'cd /home/myServerFolder/ && tail -100f log.myServerLog.txt' > /home/local/log2.txt &
PID=$!
echo "$PID"
kill -SIGINT $PID
```

This performs Ctrl + C action. But, the server log is not getting saved in my local log2.txt. Please help!

Comment: The `&` character at the end of the first line makes it run as a background job, moving on to the next commands (which eventually kill the first process). Is it possible that the `ssh` command does not have enough time to get the logs before it gets killed?

Comment: So, Any possible solution to achieve this ?

Comment: The `-f` of the `tail` command is preventing the first command from finishing, and for that reason, you need to put it in background. Removing the `-f` flag would make the command return the last 100 lines and finish, without the need to put it in background. Also, killing the process becomes unnecessary since it will finish automatically after returning the last 100 lines.

Comment: Removing -f of the tail command worked. Thank you :-)